# How to locate XPath for given tag?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, selenium2, xpath

I am trying to automate one of site and the below are the HTML code for same:

```
<a href="http://register.rediff.com/register/register.php?FormName=user_details">Create a Rediffmail account</a>
```

I want to construct XPath for "Create a Rediffmail account" hyperkink

When I construct XPath so it will display 2 match element:

```
.//a[starts-with(@href,'http://register.rediff.com/register/register.php?FormName=user_details')]
```

> There are two match element for above link how can I click only `"Create a Rediffmail account"` hyperlink?

Comment: <a href="http://register.rediff.com/register/register.php?FormName=user_details">Create a Rediffmail account</a>

above is the code for same

Answer (score 4):

You may use this-

```
Xpath1= //a[contains(.,'Create a Rediffmail account')]
```

OR

```
Xpath2=//a[contains(@href,'details')]
```

OR

```
Xpath3=.//*[@id='toprightinfo']/a[2]
```

Or you try with other Locator types as-
**LinkText**

Check I have tried & found 1 match xpath-

[image]

Comment: @Mahesh, Is it works?

Comment: I think If you are satisfied with this answer, You have to accept this answer by clicking right click.

Comment: Yes Xpath1= //a[contains(.,'Create a Rediffmail account')]  and 
accept
You may use this-

Xpath1= //a[contains(.,'Create a Rediffmail account')] 
OR

Xpath2=//a[contains(@href,'details')]   both are work fine

Comment: @Mahesh accepting answer is nothing but marking right click which is present infront of answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Mozilla FireFox.
2. Install Firebug add-on.
3. Install FirePath add-on.
4. Browse your webpage in FireFox.
5. Hit F12.
6. Click FirePath tab.
7. Inspect the element for which you want to get the Xpath.
8. Copy the xpath from the FirePath console.

It's really this simple!!!